# Confusion in the order of precedence: alkyl side-chain vs. dimethyl at different positions

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I've read that prefixes like 'tert-butyl, 'sec-butyl' and have been discarded while 'iso-propyl' is still retained by IUPAC. So I wrote another name according to the general rules. Is it correct? If not please correct me.

---

(The structure in question is framed)
[image: The structure in question is framed]

---

**EDIT:** When I typed the name *[here](http://opsin.ch.cam.ac.uk/)* it gave a slightly different structure so I tried putting 5-(1-methylpropyl) first, as in 5-(1-methylpropyl)-2,7-dimethylnonane, which gave the correct structure.

---

**So, my question now is**, since both substituents have same alphabetical order, why do we write 5-(1-methylpropyl) first?

Comment: I think your naming is completely right.

Comment: @Mockingbird no, it was slightly incorrect, please see my edited question.

Comment: I think it's just an convention..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your starting point is correct. According to the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001),* the name **5-(*sec*-butyl)-2,7-dimethylnonane** is no longer recommended. (The prefix ‘*sec*-butyl’ was still contained in the 1993 recommendations.)

The names that are proposed in the question, **2,7-dimethyl-5-(1-methylpropyl)nonane** and **5-(1-methylpropyl)-2,7-dimethylnonane,** are unambiguous and describe the same structure. There may be many different ways to draw the structure of such branched alkanes. If you enter these names into the [Open Parser for Systematic IUPAC nomenclature (OPSIN)](http://opsin.ch.cam.ac.uk/), which is mentioned in the question, the results are as follows:

[image: 2,7-dimethyl-5-(1-methylpropyl)nonane]
2,7-dimethyl-5-(1-methylpropyl)nonane

[image: 5-(1-methylpropyl)-2,7-dimethylnonane]
5-(1-methylpropyl)-2,7-dimethylnonane

The structures may look different at first glance, but they actually describe the same compound. In this respect, there is no difference between 2,7-dimethyl-5-(1-methylpropyl)nonane and 5-(1-methylpropyl)-2,7-dimethylnonane. However, the name 5-(1-methylpropyl)-2,7-dimethylnonane is not in accordance with IUPAC nomenclature since ‘methyl’ is earlier alphabetically than ‘methylpropyl’. Therefore, the name **2,7-dimethyl-5-(1-methylpropyl)nonane** is a correct IUPAC name.

Anyway, the *preferred* IUPAC name (PIN) according to current recommendations is **5-(butan-2-yl)-2,7-dimethylnonane.**